# It is possible to send data to some applications via ADB?

Tags: adb

I am new to android development and development android apps (writing java or apk code) and I want to know if it is even posssible to send some data like email-password to an applications using `adb` for example, open play store and login with credentials.

I have not read at all the documentation at android developer, but i want to know.

If this is even so far to my approach, which way could i control my device by sending data or manipulate some apps by using `adb`?, I know that i can use basic functionalities like sending files using `adb push` or explore some other services like `adb shell` which other ways i can control an android device?

Comment: You can customize your app to listen to an intent and get data from it. Through adb, you can send an intent and pass data into it. That's all you can do. Another way is to interact with UI fields. Through `input text` command you can fill an active field with text.